# Vector 3 Position on different Screen Size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

so this is what happens when Im using vector 3 on my game I want my vector 3 to be on specific position for different screen sizes? is that possible? here is my codes

```
 public virtual void ShuffleButton()
    {
       Vector3 buttonFirst = gameButtons[0].transform.position;
       buttonFirst.x += 297f;
       gameButtons[0].transform.position = buttonFirst;

       Vector3 buttonSecond = gameButtons[1].transform.position;
       buttonSecond.x -= 74.25f;
       gameButtons[1].transform.position = buttonSecond;

       Vector3 buttonThird = gameButtons[2].transform.position;
       buttonThird.x += 74.25f;
       gameButtons[2].transform.position = buttonThird;

       Vector3 buttonFourth = gameButtons[3].transform.position;
       buttonFourth.x -= 148.5f;
       gameButtons[3].transform.position = buttonFourth;

       Vector3 buttonFifth = gameButtons[4].transform.position;
       buttonFifth.x -= 148.5f;
       gameButtons[4].transform.position = buttonFifth;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the position conversion functions like `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint()`. These can be found in the Unity Camera class documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html

If, for example, you want to place a Sprite in the top-left corner, regardless of screen size, you would use the screen or viewport space. The position of the sprite will have to be translated from this screen/viewport space to world space. You could use `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint()` for this.

However, Unity uses three viewspaces: Screen, World and Viewport. You should read up on all three as your problem stems from the fact that you are trying to use world coordinates (transform.position) to set the position of UI elements (which use either the screen or world space; this is dependent on the parent Canvas settings)

Comment: is switching to gridlayout for buttons good? I mean im pretty new to Unity and I can't understand most of the methods and syntax available and im pretty familiar to GridLayout hehe is it possible to do the same output?? :))

Comment: @NicoleErasga Using a GridLayout is not particularly relevant to this problem, I'm afraid. It can help, but screen, world and viewport spaces are fundamental concepts in Unity, as are Vector2 and Vector3's. As others have said (and me too), if you can't understand the methods and syntax, you should read up on them and learn them, instead of searching for easier alternatives that do not require extra effort.

Comment: oh thanks for the info will definitely try and learn this :)) thank you! for such insights :)))